# Value of a function at 0

Tags: real-analysis

I am reading a paper which asserts that the value of the function $f(x) = x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ at $x=0$ is equal to $0$. I can believe that this is so if I write $f(x) = e^{{\frac{1}{x}}{{\rm ln}(x)}}$, but I want a rigorous proof of this fact! Is this function even defined at $x=0?$

Comment: The function $f(x)=x^{\frac{1}{x}}$ is defined for $x>0$ and then if you let $x \to 0$ (through positive values only of course), $\frac{\ln x}{x} \to -\infty$ trivially so $f(x) \to 0$ and the convention is to take that as the value $f(0)$ which apriori is not defined

Answer (score 5):

The expression $x^{1/x}$ is not defined when $x=0$, because $1/0$ has no value.

What you *can* ask is whether the function defined on $(0,\infty)$ can be *extended continuously* to a function defined on $[0,\infty)$. (Such an extended function cannot be defined by the expression $x^{1/x}$ at $0$, of course). This is the same as asking for
$$ \lim_{x\to 0^+} x^{1/x} $$
and the way to investigate that would indeed be to look at how its logarithm behaves as $x$ approaches $0$ from above.

Since $$ \log(x^{1/x}) = \frac1x\log(x) = - \frac1x \log \frac1x $$
which clearly goes to $-\infty$ when $\frac1x$ goes to $+\infty$, it is easy to show explicitly that the limit above must be $0$.

Answer (score 4):

The limit of $x^{1/x}$ as $x \to 0+$ is indeed $0$, as you see by writing $f(x) = \exp(\ln(x)/x)$.  The limit as $x \to 0-$, on the other hand, is certainly not $0$ (not even defined, if you want to stick to real numbers).  **At** $x=0$ the expression is undefined because $1/0$ is  undefined.

You can, if you wish, define the function $f(x)$ to be $0$ at $x=0$.  You can even say that is the "usual convention".  But it's not something that can be proven: there is nothing there to prove.

Comment: Indeed. For negative $x$, we have tom pass to a branch of the complex logarithm. So, we are only interested in approaching $0$ from the right.